# watch command alias expansion

Tags: bash, alias

If a run the `watch` command containing an alias, it will not expand the alias. I have tried both with single quote and double quotes, in fact given the following alias:

```
# alias ll
alias ll='ls -l --color=tty'
```

The following command will fail

```
# watch ll
sh: ll: command not found
```

Shouldn't command line expansion work in this case?

Comment: I thought maybe we could use `"watch -x bash -i -c ll"` (the "-x" tells watch not to use it's own "sh -c" to execute the given command.) But it successfully runs 'll' once, then backgrounds and stops the process.  I don't know why.

Answer (score 198):

Aliases are only expanded as the first argument, or after another alias with a trailing space on the end of the command.

From `bash`'s `help alias`:

> A trailing space in VALUE causes the next word to be checked for alias substitution when the alias is expanded.

To do this, try the following:

```
alias watch='watch '
alias ll='ls -l --color=tty'
watch ll
```

Bear in mind that some versions of `watch` strip colours by default, on some versions this can be stopped by using `--color` or `-G`.

Comment: This is absolutely awesome answer! Thanks and +1 of course.

Comment: Thanks... For all this time, I used to 1. type ll, 2. press ctrl+alt+e, 3. then prefix watch. This is a time saver.

Comment: Unfortunately this method has a limitation that you cannot provide options to `watch` because the alias has to be the next word, whereas `watch` needs its arguments before the command to run.  If you tried `watch -n 10 <alias>`, bash won't expand the alias.  To work around it, you need an alias that includes the options you want (e.g., `alias watch-10='watch -n 10 '), still with a trailing space.

Comment: Is there a similar approach to do bash function expansion in a similar manner?

Comment: > A trailing space in VALUE causes the next word to be checked for alias substitution when the alias is


-----
That abit confusing. It works also in other shells, but dont get the reason.

Comment: if trying to get other commands to work, the space is useful there as well (e.g., `alias shellcheck='shellcheck --color '`) :)

Answer (score 16):

Maybe we could manually expand the alias before watch sees it?

```
watch $(alias ll | cut -d\' -f2)
```

#### Explanation

The output of `alias ll` looks like:

```
$ alias ll
alias ll='ls -lAGh'
```

So we set cut's delimeter to be single quote, and cut the 2nd field, leaving:

```
ls -lAGh
```

ie the expanded alias. *That* then forms the args given to `watch`.

### Make a function to do it

```
function watcha {
    watch $(alias "$@" | cut -d\' -f2)
}
```

Then,

```
watcha ll
```

works as desired. This is awful and will fail in all sorts of situations. Sorry.

Comment: +1 for enginuity and admintting to the failure cases :)

Comment: These answers will fail if the alias has any apostrophes (single quotes) in it. The `watcha` function will blow up if you try to pass arguments.

Comment: Also it fails if your alias is a function... Nice try though... UpVote

Comment: very nice, i created an alias check around, https://gist.github.com/cinatic/5e54a87a1bef019fe1848e00c2bf86f1

Answer (score 5):

Another trick that I use (specifically for aliasing `kubectl` to `k`) is to create a symlink instead of an alias. That way the symlink still is found by `watch` and no trickery is required.

The downside of this is that you have to do this for every alias you want to work, and I'm not sure how it'd work for shell builtins.

Comment: In addition to shell builtins, this would also not work for binaries that check what name they have been called with. This includes busybox, [rustup shims that allow +stable and per-directory overrides], and bash, that disables some features if called as `/something/sh`

Answer (score 1):

There's a custom program to handle this over at [github.com/antonmedv/watch](https://github.com/antonmedv/watch). It supports multiple shells. Of course because it's custom software to install it's OK for your normal computers but not helpful on random servers you might be connected to. Here's how I run it so I can watch my zsh aliases and functions:

```
function watch-zsh() {
  WATCH_COMMAND='zsh -ci' /usr/local/bin/watch "$@"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one that uses the `--color` option and allows you to use the `-n` argument to specify a refresh interval.

```bash
swatch_usage() {
    cat <<EOF >&2
NAME
       swatch - execute a program periodically with "watch". Supports aliases.

SYNOPSIS
       swatch [options] command

OPTIONS
       -n, --interval seconds (default: 1)
              Specify update interval.  The command will not allow quicker than
              0.1 second interval.
EOF
}

swatch() {
    if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        swatch_usage
        return 1
    fi
    seconds=1

    case "$1" in
    -n)
        seconds="$2"
        args=${*:3}
        ;;
    -h)
        swatch_usage
        return 1
        ;;
    *)
        seconds=1
        args=${*:1}
        ;;

    esac

    watch --color -n "$seconds" --exec bash -ic "$args || true"
}
```

I only needed color and timing support,
but I'm sure you could add more if you wanted.

The meat of the function is that it executes your command with bash directly in interactive mode and can thus use any aliases or commands that are normally available to you in bash.

I'm not that experienced with scripting so fair warning, your mileage may vary. Sometimes I have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> a few times to get it to stop, but for what it's worth, I've been using it frequently for 6 months without issue.

Gist form: https://gist.github.com/ablacklama/550420c597f9599cf804d57dd6aad131

Comment: (1) It seems to me that your usage message is not very clear.  (2) The `return` statement in the `swatch_usage` function serves no purpose.  (3) If you run `swatch -h`, it displays the usage message and then runs `watch` on a null command.  (4) In the final command line, `$seconds` should be `"$seconds"`. (5) Naturally, this will stumble if the command has special characters in it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, i updated it.

Answer (score 0):

I thought here basic problem is while executing `watch`, the argument is given to "`sh -c`" which means if alias `ll` is not defined in `sh(dash shell's)` environment then it will not expand it. But I was wrong and this is not the case, Chris' answer above is right.

Comment: Not exactly. Try `watch 'alias ll="ls -l --color=tty"; type ll; ll'`.

Comment: +1 for immediate response to verify it. I was wrong above.

Comment: @ChrisDown, so even if watch uses "`sh -c`" the your explanation is applicable for `sh` too. Am I right?

Comment: That depends on what shell is being used as `sh`. Notice that this *does* work: `sh -c $'alias ll="ls -l --color=tty"\ntype ll\nll'`