# Watch-command-alias-expansion AND need to use quotes

Tags: watch, slurm

My questions is similar to the [watch question here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25327/watch-command-alias-expansion) but with a twist. I need to use quotes, which seem to be stripped by an aliased watch.

I want run watch on a custom slurm squeue command:

```
$alias squeue_personal='squeue -o "%.18i %.9P %.8j %.8u %.216t %.10M %.6D %R    %V   %S  %Z"'
$alias watch='watch '
```

**NOTE:** [*as per the other watch question*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25327/watch-command-alias-expansion)

But this still doesn't work. Because the aliased watch strips out quotations:

```
Every 2.0s: squeue -o %.18i %.9P %.8j %.8u %.2t %.10M %.6D %R    %V   %S  %Z                                                                                            Fri Jul  6 12:06:57 2018

squeue: error: Unrecognized option: %.9P
Usage: squeue [-A account] [--clusters names] [-i seconds] [--job jobid]
              [-n name] [-o format] [-p partitions] [--qos qos]
              [--reservation reservation] [--sort fields] [--start]
              [--step step_id] [-t states] [-u user_name] [--usage]
              [-L licenses] [-w nodes] [-ahjlrsv]
```

If I don't use aliases everything is fine. e.g. the following works:

```
$watch 'squeue  -o "%.18i %.9P %.8j %.8u %.2t %.10M %.6D %R    %V   %S  %Z"'
```

I'm sure the solution is some small twist to [the other watch question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25327/watch-command-alias-expansion) but I don't know what.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`watch` concatenates its command line arguments, joining them with spaces and passes the result as a string to `sh -c`. So `watch ls -l "foo bar"` becomes the same as `watch ls -l foo bar`, and you get a similar problem with `squeue`. You have two choices:

1. Add explicit quotes for the shell that `watch` starts. As you actually did in the last example. It's just that when your alias expands the double-quotes are not quoted. The outer quotes just quote the alias when it's defined. They don't act on the command line when the alias is expanded.

   So, any of these:

   ```
   watch squeue -o '"%.18i %.9P %.8j %.8u %.2t %.10M %.6D %R    %V   %S  %Z"'

   watch squeue -o \"%.18i %.9P %.8j %.8u %.2t %.10M %.6D %R    %V   %S  %Z\"

   alias watch='watch '
   alias sq='squeue -o \"%.18i %.9P %.8j %.8u %.2t %.10M %.6D %R    %V   %S  %Z\"'
   watch sq

   alias sq=\''squeue -o "%.18i %.9P %.8j %.8u %.2t %.10M %.6D %R    %V   %S  %Z"'\'
   watch sq
   ```

   **NOTE:** You can use `set -x` and run `watch >/dev/null` to see the command that the shell actually runs, you'll see there if the quotes actually get passed along to `watch`.
2. Tell `watch` to skip the shell, and to run the command directly. That way, the separate command line arguments stay separate. [Man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/watch.1.html):

   > `-x`, `--exec`
   >            Pass command to `exec(2)` instead of `sh -c` which reduces the
   >          need to use extra quoting to get the desired effect.

   ```
   watch -x squeue -o "%.18i %.9P %.8j %.8u %.2t %.10M %.6D %R    %V   %S  %Z"

   alias watchx='watch -x '
   alias sq='squeue -o "%.18i %.9P %.8j %.8u %.216t %.10M %.6D %R    %V   %S  %Z"'
   watchx sq
   ```