# How to use alias to a watch command which include another alias and some double and single quotes in the latter alias?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, watch

`alias vov="scontrol -o show nodes | grep -e \"-lkeb\" -e \"-gpu\"| awk '{ printf(\"%-15s%-9s%-7s%-18s%-11s%-9s%s\n\",  substr(\$1, 10), substr(\$4, 10), substr(\$5, 8), substr(\$9, 6), substr(substr(\$23, 12)/1024,0,5), substr(substr(\$24, 10)/1024,0,5), substr(\$38, 11))}' | awk '{printf(\"%-15s%-7s%-9s%-18s%-7s%-9s%50-s%2-s%9-s%9-s%9-s\n\", \$1, \$3, \$2, \$4, \$5, \$6, \"|\"\$7, \"|\", \$3-\$2, \$5-\$6, substr(\$4,length(\$4))-substr(\$7,length(\$7)))}' | awk '\$11 != 0' | awk 'BEGIN {print \"NodeName       CPUTot CPUAlloc Gres              MemTot MemAlloc AllocTres                                           CPUAvail MemAvail GPUAvail CPU/GPU\"}{print \$0 FS \$9/\$11}'"`

The above code works well when I write it to my `.bashrc` file.

`watch "scontrol -o show nodes | grep -e \"-lkeb\" -e \"-gpu\"| awk '{ printf(\"%-15s%-9s%-7s%-18s%-11s%-9s%s\n\",  substr(\$1, 10), substr(\$4, 10), substr(\$5, 8), substr(\$9, 6), substr(substr(\$23, 12)/1024,0,5), substr(substr(\$24, 10)/1024,0,5), substr(\$38, 11))}' | awk '{printf(\"%-15s%-7s%-9s%-18s%-7s%-9s%50-s%2-s%9-s%9-s%9-s\n\", \$1, \$3, \$2, \$4, \$5, \$6, \"|\"\$7, \"|\", \$3-\$2, \$5-\$6, substr(\$4,length(\$4))-substr(\$7,length(\$7)))}' | awk '\$11 != 0' | awk 'BEGIN {print \"NodeName       CPUTot CPUAlloc Gres              MemTot MemAlloc AllocTres                                           CPUAvail MemAvail GPUAvail CPU/GPU\"}{print \$0 FS \$9/\$11}'"`

The above code also works well when I paste it to my terminal (`/bin/bash`). Actually the code to be watched is just the `vov`.

But I met some issues:

1. I can not use `watch vov` in my terminal (`/bin/bash`).
2. I can not use `alias` to assign the second code (longer version) to another variable in my `.bashrc`.
3. I can not use `alias` to assign `watch vov` (shorter version) to another variable in my `.bashrc`.

Can you help me to solve the 3 issues?

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25327/watch-command-alias-expansion -- duplicate?

Comment: Also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/453858/117549

Answer (score 0):

I've run into that same trouble with `watch` and shell aliases. I'm not sure why the aliases aren't available to watch, but you can solve (or work-around) this by putting your aliases into a shellscript, and calling `watch` on that.

Create a file called `vov` with the shebang `#!/bin/bash` on the first line and then the `scontrol...etc` on subsequent lines, save the file, `chmod +x vov`, `mv vov ~/.local/bin/` (or some other place on your `$PATH`).

Then you can do `watch -t -n 1 -c vov`

I forget what flags `watch` needs so I have a shellscript called `sho` that looks like `watch -t -n 1 -c "$1"` so with that you could do `sho vov`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have any solution without another seperate script?

Comment: No. You should either: **1)** just get used to using custom scripts because they're useful (I have `~/bin` on my `$PATH` to make this more convenient), or **2)** troubleshoot the scenario more to get a bare-minimum repeatable instance (no need for giant 1liners which detract from the question *(unnecessary code make it harder for people to know what you're talking about))* and ask a more clearn+informed question. #1 achieves your objective. #2 is interesting and I'd like to know what's up with shell aliases + watch in this context too, but it might not be worth the time and effort.