# How can I alias `...` to `../..` in Bash?

Tags: bash, alias

How can I alias `...` to `../..` in Bash?

I am aware that other answers allow `alias '...'='cd ../..'` but I'd like to be able to address the directory two levels up with other commands, allowing for:

```bash
cd ...
ls ...
realpath ...
```

I have tried `alias '...'='../..'` but when trying to use this I get the following:

```bash
$ alias '...'='../..'
$ type ...
... is aliased to '../..'
$ cd ...
bash: cd: ...: No such file or directory
```

I'm aware aliases are intended for use with commands. Is there a way to achieve the same functionality for a path in this case?

Comment: Similar, if not a dupe of [Paths as bash aliases only work in parent directories?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/694182)

Comment: Short of fixing the OS's path resolving logic or intercepting all system calls that take pathnames to preprocess them, any solutions would likely have problems with one or more of a) using `...` as a part of a path (`cat .../somefile`), b) using `...` through a variable (`f=.../foo; cat "$f"`), and/or c) non-file arguments that contain `...` (`git commit -m "let's see if this works..."`). Which isn't to say you shouldn't do that if you like the idea, just that there might be some gotchas that make it less generally useful than it could be.

Comment: Not a serious answer, but `ln -s ../.. ...` :)

Comment: A not terribly good idea: redefining cd (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28783509/override-a-builtin-command-with-an-alias). Check if $1=="..." then builtin cd  ../.. else cd $1.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If switching to zsh is an option, you could use global aliases there for that:

```
alias -g ...=../..
```

But in any case that's only expanded when `...` is recognised as a full delimited token on its own. It will be expanded in `echo ...` or `echo ...> file` or `(echo ...)` but not in `echo .../x` or `echo ~/...` or `echo "..."`).

Normal csh-style aliases, whether it's in bash or zsh are only expanded when in command position or after another alias expansion ending in a blank character. In zsh, though, if you set the `autocd` option, entering `../..` or another directory as the command name gets turned into `cd ../..`, so

```
$ set -o autocd
$ alias ...=../.. ....=../../..
$ ...
```

Would be a way to `cd` into `../..`, but then again so would `alias ...='cd ../..'` or `...() cd ../..`.

A better approach that [I've been using for many years](https://comp.unix.shell.narkive.com/lH6kG84K/reintroducing-fish-the-friendly-interactive-shell#post72) is to bind the <kbd>.</kbd> key to something that inserts `/..` instead of `.` if what's left of the cursor ends in `..`:

```
magic-dot() {
  if [[ $LBUFFER = (|*[[:blank:]/]).. ]]; then
    repeat ${NUMERIC-1} LBUFFER+=/..
  else
    zle self-insert
  fi
}
zle -N magic-dot
bindkey . magic-dot
```

Then entering `...` gets immediately and visually transformed to `../..` and pressing <kbd>.</kbd> again changes it to `../../..` and so on. If in `emacs` mode, `..` followed by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>,<kbd>.</kbd> makes it `../../../../..` for instance (`/..` appended 4 times) using the usual *NUMERIC* prefix handling.

It used to sometimes get in the way when copy/pasting things that contain `...`, but that's no longer a problem now that bracketed paste support has been introduced. To enter a literal `...`, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> before the third `.` or use backslashes, quoting or anything that makes so what's left of the cursor (`$LBUFFER` above) doesn't end in `<blanks-or-slash>..` such as `.\..`, `..\.`, `whatever/'...'`...

An intentional limitation of the above is that for instance in `sort -o...`, the `...` is not expanded. Use `sort -o ...` instead. Same goes for `cd '.../***'` -> `cd ...'/***'`. You can change the test above to `[[ $LBUFFER = (|*[^.]).. ]]` for the `...` to be expanded to `../..` in more contexts although that would increase the probability of it being expanded in places you wouldn't like it to.

We can make the numeric argument handling a bit more useful by allowing `cd Alt+4.` to `cd` 4 levels up (expand to `../../../..`) for instance with:

```
magic-dot() {
  if (( NUMERIC )) && [[ $LBUFFER = (|*[[:blank:]/:]) ]]; then
    LBUFFER+=..
    (( NUMERIC-- ))
  fi
    
  if [[ $LBUFFER = (|*[[:blank:]/]).. ]]; then
    repeat ${NUMERIC-1} LBUFFER+=/..
  else
    zle self-insert
  fi
}
zle -N magic-dot
bindkey . magic-dot
```

As mentioned by @Gilles in comment, recent versions of bash have added limited support for editing the line buffer in commands bound to keys, so you could do something similar there with:

```
insert_before_cursor() {
  # for the equivalent of zsh's repeat $1 LBUFFER+=$2
  local i
  for (( i = 0; i < $1; i++ )); do
    READLINE_LINE=${READLINE_LINE:0:READLINE_POINT}$2${READLINE_LINE:READLINE_POINT}
    (( READLINE_POINT += ${#2} ))
  done
}

magic-dot() {
  (( ${READLINE_ARGUMENT-1} > 0 )) || return
  if [[ -v READLINE_ARGUMENT && ${READLINE_LINE:0:READLINE_POINT} = ?(*[[:blank:]/]) ]]; then
    insert_before_cursor 1 ..
    (( READLINE_ARGUMENT-- ))
  fi

  if [[ ${READLINE_LINE:0:READLINE_POINT} = ?(*[[:blank:]/]).. ]]; then
    insert_before_cursor "${READLINE_ARGUMENT-1}" /..
  else
    insert_before_cursor "${READLINE_ARGUMENT-1}" .
  fi
}
bind -x '".":magic-dot'

# work around a bug in current versions of bash for the numeric
# argument to work properly, that means however that you lose the
# insert-last-argument normally bound to Meta-. (also on Meta-_)
bind -x '"\e.":magic-dot'
```

You need bash 4.0 or above for `$READLINE_LINE` (not `$READLINE_LINE_BUFFER` as misspelled in some of the documentation), and `$READLINE_POINT`, and 5.2 or above for `$READLINE_ARGUMENT`, though as noted above it currently doesn't work properly yet.

Comment: `alias -g ...=../..` is not really useful because it only works when `...` is alone, it doesn't make `.../foo` work as an equivalent of `../../foo`. Whereas `magic-dot` is genuinely useful. (But I think modern versions of bash can do it so it's no longer a reason to switch to zsh.)

Comment: I wonder if it is at least theoretically possible to implement `magic-dot` for bash instead of zsh. It sounds cool, but I can't switch to zsh on my company PB because many tools depend on Bash.

Comment: @Neinstein, that reminds me of the 90s when it wasn't uncommon for people to get stuck with csh because that was what everyone else was using, and you had to go through hoops to be able to use a proper shell. Here it's not so bad, zsh has a ksh-emulation mode with which it should be able to run most bash code. In any case, using zsh as your interactive shell doesn't prevent you from running bash scripts or scripts in any language. Anyway, see edit for a bash version.

Comment: Neat, I'll try it! re bash - in my case it's not really the scripts but the whole environment. I'm a simulational physicist, and half of the codes are very obscure, were written by some random genius in like the 70s, half in Bash half in Fortran, documented in French or German, and  used by about 20 people around the whole world. I'm happy if I can pray them to compile and run even in Bash, let alone challenging the gods of doom by using an alternative shell.

Answer (score 12):

You can't use aliases for this, aliases are about things you execute, not things you pass to a command as arguments. You could use a variable, but that would mean typing something slightly different. But if you use a short variable name, it can be just two characters:

```
$ pwd
/home/terdon/foo/bar
$ v="../.."
$ realpath "$v"
/home/terdon
```

If that works for you, you can add the variable definition to your `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` files and you will then have access to it in your shell sessions:

```
v="../.."
```

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple ways you can reach your goal

##### METHOD 1: Modify the source code for bash

This method is version specific but is still recommended as its the good way to get things done. What I did is modified `builtins/cd.def` such that before it checks for absolute path it checks if the first argument is `...` if so it sets the `dirname` to `../..` (sounds like alias only)

**STEP 1:** Download [bash-5.1.16.tar](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-5.1.16.tar.gz)

```
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-5.1.16.tar.gz
```

**STEP 2:** Fetch & apply the patch [bash_5.16_cd_three_dot.patch](https://gist.github.com/s0ubhik/6685effe6e46f6a840bb480c5d657933)

```
tar -xf bash-5.1.16.tar.gz
cd bash-5.1.16
wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/s0ubhik/6685effe6e46f6a840bb480c5d657933/raw/5736ce64cbb0b009d872c21f40d69c8ee2942b74/bash_5.16_cd_three_dot.patch
patch -p0 < bash_5.16_cd_three_dot.patch
```

**STEP 3:** Compile and run

```
./configure
make
./bash
```

[image: cd ... bash]

##### METHOD 2: Enable autocd in shopt

This methods does not do exactly what you want but i think it is better rather using clever alias techniques

```
shopt -s autocd
```

Now if you want to go one directory back just use `..` and for two `../..`
[image: autocd cd]

##### METHOD 3: Use clever alias

This method works but is not recommend as might be problematic to various scripts the use `cd`. you may add this to your `.bashrc` or create a seprate file and then include the file in `.bashrc`

```
cd_mod(){
  if [ "$1" == "..." ]; then
    \cd ../../
  else
    \cd $@
  fi
}

alias cd=cd_mod
```

[image: cd_mod cd]

Comment: Why the name "cleaver alias"?  Or is it a typo for "clever"?

Comment: Modifying the source code for Bash is probably not recommended, unless you convince the Bash upstream to merge the change.

Comment: I don't see how an alias would be problematic, but modifying the source code wouldn't be.

Comment: question says " I'd like to be able to address the directory two levels up **with other commands**", which none of your suggestions accomplishes.  Now, patching the Bash source code could indeed accomplish the goal, but not by changing the `cd` builtin.  It would have to be done in global argument processing, such as where `~` gets expanded to the home directory.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use alias directly because `...` is an argument to `cd`, but I have seen some people alias `cd..` to be `cd ..`, so you could do similar with all of the commands:

```
alias cd...='cd ../..'
```

On the other hand...

```
$ cat ~/mycd 
if [ "$1" = '...' ]
then
  # Use \cd to prevent recursion
  \cd ../..
else
  \cd "$1"
fi
```

And then

```
alias cd=". ~/mycd"
```

Alternatively,

```
mycd() { if [ "$1" = '...' ]; then \cd ../..; else \cd "$1"; fi; }
alias cd="mycd"
```

Comment: You could also do `alias cd='cd ' ...=../..` as aliases that end in a space make the next word get checked for alias expansion too. But that has the same problem, you have to do it individually for each command, and it only works to expand `...` in the position right after the command word, and only if it's `...` exactly, so `cp foo.txt .../bar` won't work

Comment: @Kusalananda I was thinking of not quoting $1 in the \cd $1 case ... but it does look like cd "" is the same as cd with no args, so I guess it is fine!

Comment: @rrauenza You could also use `cd "$@"` to pass exactly the arguments that were passed to the function.  Note too that you can avoid that extra alias by naming the function `cd`.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning how you change into a directory that's _actually_ called `...` (you'll need to write it as `./...`).

Comment: question says " I'd like to be able to address the directory two levels up **with other commands**", which none of your suggestions accomplishes.